# Eclipse shows an error on every function and I dont know why

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello I´m pretty new to java and eclipse. When im writing a function, eclipse always shows an error (at the line public double makeChange(double itemCost, double dollarsProvided)) {  and I dont know why. This is the Code:

```
package lernen;

public class udacity {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

public double makeChange(double itemCost, double dollarsProvided) {
    double change = dollarsProvided - itemCost ;
    return change;
} 

}

}
```

It says: Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
     LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
    - Syntax error on token "rollDice", AnnotationName expected after 
     this token
    - Syntax error, insert "[ ]" to complete Dimension
    - Illegal modifier for parameter rollDice; only final is permitted

Can you help me?

Comment: First of all, some concepts, in Java we use capital letter for class names, and there is not a function, and yes a method. And the reason for the errors, your method makeChange(...) is inside the main method. Another rule, you cannot write a method inside the other one.

Comment: In programming, each and character matters. So when you put the closing brace of main() { } **after** the next method declaration, you already have invalid syntax. Beyond that: start with proper indentation. As soon as you indent nested levels a bit, you quickly see when things are nested for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a method inside a main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 double d = makeChange(0,0);

}

public static double makeChange(double itemCost, double dollarsProvided) {
    double change = dollarsProvided - itemCost ;
    return change;
}
```

Comment: just a litle thing, the call to the makeChange(...) method wont work like your writting. Inside a main method it does need an instance class.

Comment: @Karpinski its a static method it can be called without an class instance.

Comment: Ow that is ok, I refered to the original method, it wasn't static.